# Latex Bib file not working

Tags: bibliographies

I have written my thesis chapters in Latex, and now that I'm submitting them, I'm trying to use the latex template made available by the thesis office. A copy of the whole thing can be found here:https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-template-for-the-university-of-utah/ztbxkqkpctpw

I have been having problems with being able to do anything with the references. The file above uses \bibliography{\jobname}} for the references, which I believe means it refers to the sample-thesis-0.bib file. The bib file is nothing like I have worked with before. I created my bib files before, but the format here is unfamiliar. When I instead try to create a new bib file and use https://www.bibme.org/bibtex for creating my citations, the reference section comes out empty, and I get an error: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{thebibliography}"

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: A preliminary comment: the bibme.org site has no knownn official connection to BibTeX. Use it at your own peril.